# Interpretation of Hubble Diagram

Tags: astrophysics, doppler-effect, redshift

[image: Hubble Diagram]

According to my professor's notes, this is the Hubble Diagram. Unfortunately, I do not know what the y-axis is referring to. Is it the absolute luminosity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quantity $m-M$ is the difference between the apparent magnitude and absolute magnitude, and is referred to as the [*distance modulus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_modulus), $\mu$. The relationship between $\mu$ and distance, $d$, is logarithmic, i.e.
$$\mu=5\log d+5+\text{corrections}$$
where the correcting terms account for observational effects. In cosmological cases, we substitute $D_L$, the so-called *luminosity distance*, for $d$, where $D_L=d(1+z)$, for redshift $z$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\mu&=5\log D_L+\text{constants}\\
&=5\log(d(1+z))+\text{constants}\\
&=5\log d+5\log(1+z)+\text{constants}
\end{align}$$
We should therefore see a linear relationship between $\mu$ and $\log(1+z)$ - which we do.